# PHP processed, HTML-CSS, CMS-agnostic, contact now panel

Tags: php, html, css

I develop a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)-agnostic PHP formatted HTML-CSS "contact now" panel, sticky in the bottom of a website screen.
The code is tested and works as can be seen from the following image.
I ask a review of the code, primarily about the everything-first **CSS**.

Sidenote: I format the HTML in PHP because PHP supports `include` which I use a lot to well organize the code, generally without caring about the output if the code works, especially in a simple project.

[image: Screenshot showing menu at bottom of browser window]

### Files

#### main_box.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main_box/mobile_general_structure.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div dir="rtl" class="cacb_main_box">
            <?php
                include './phone_box.php';
                include './email_box.php';
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### phone_box.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/phone_box/mobile_general_structure.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cacb_phone_box">
            <a class="cacb_phone_link" href="tel:NUMBER">
                <img class="cacb_phone_icon" src="./images/whatsapp.svg"></img>
                <span class="cacb_phone_text">WhatsApp call</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### email_box.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/email_box/mobile_general_structure.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cacb_email_box">
            <a class="cacb_email_link" href="/contact_form.php">
                <img class="cacb_email_icon" src="./images/email.svg"></img>
                <span class="cacb_email_text">Send an email</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### css/main_box/general_mobile_structure.css

```css
.cacb_main_box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* column */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2a4b8d;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 18%);
}
```

#### css/phone_box/general_mobile_structure.css

```css
.cacb_phone_box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50%;
}

.cacb_phone_link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; /* Fixes continuing line problem */
}

.cacb_phone_icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.cacb_phone_text {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

#### css/email_box/general_mobile_structure.css

```css
.cacb_email_box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50%;
}

.cacb_email_link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; /* Fixes continuing line problem */
}

.cacb_email_icon {
    color: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.cacb_email_text {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS looks good to me, although I would reconsider using `z-index: auto;`. I assume you want your *contact-now* panel to always appear on top of other content, even if it is not included as the last element? In that case a high valid for `z-index` is needed. If you always put your *contact-now* panel last in the `<body>` tag, and no other elements have a positive `z-index`, then `z-index: auto;` is not needed. See: [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

I don't quite understand why you need to repeat the CSS for the `phone_box` and the `email_box`?. Those are virtually the same. Having one file will be enough and saves some resources.

Your use of PHP's `include()` doesn't seem to work out as it should. If you were to look at the source code in your browser, you would see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main_box/mobile_general_structure.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div dir="rtl" class="cacb_main_box">
            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/phone_box/mobile_general_structure.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cacb_phone_box">
            <a class="cacb_phone_link" href="tel:NUMBER">
                <img class="cacb_phone_icon" src="./images/whatsapp.svg"></img>
                <span class="cacb_phone_text">WhatsApp call</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/email_box/mobile_general_structure.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cacb_email_box">
            <a class="cacb_email_link" href="/contact_form.php">
                <img class="cacb_email_icon" src="./images/email.svg"></img>
                <span class="cacb_email_text">Send an email</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>        </div>
</body>
```

This HTML is [clearly not well-formed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics#anatomy_of_an_html_document). You should not have nested `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>` tags. Yes, it works, but only because your browser is fault tolerant.

Once you've opened the `<body>` you only need to use content tags. For instance, **email_box.php** could be like this:

```
<div class="cacb_email_box">
    <a class="cacb_email_link" href="/contact_form.php">
        <img class="cacb_email_icon" src="./images/email.svg"></img>
        <span class="cacb_email_text">Send an email</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

And then the HTML looks fine.

Comment: I don't understand why you said "You seem to misunderstand how PHP's `include()` works", I used it to include other HTML files because HTML doesn't have an include internal function of its own, which is perfectly fine if HTML is putted inside a PHP frame.

Comment: I say that only because you end up with malformed HTML with nested [<html>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) tags. HTML itself does have some sort of "include" tag, see: [<iframe>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), but please don't use it here, this is not the right use case for it.

Comment: I think you should change the phrasing of what you said about me in regard to `include()` because a special use doesn't mean someone doesn't understand how something works (or should work for that matter).

Comment: Sorry, no offense was intended, I'll change the wording.